# width is not being applied for columns in semantic ui table

Tags: css, vuejs2, semantic-ui

I am using [Vuetable](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2). and Its default CSS for tables are Semantic UI.

I want to show a full-width table with all columns fully expanded to their widths.

[image]

This is how the table is being shown

```
<div id="table-wrapper" :class="['vuetable-wrapper ui basic segment', loading]">
  <div class="handle">
    <vuetable ref="vuetable"
      api-url="/v1/users"
      :fields="fields"
      pagination-path=""
      data-path="data"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :sort-order="sortOrder"
      :append-params="moreParams"
      @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData"
      @vuetable:initialized="onInitialized"
      @vuetable:loading="showLoader"
      @vuetable:loaded="hideLoader"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

I have set handle's overflow-x to scroll.

```
.handle[data-v-051ed7b2] {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

When Vuetable get created the default CSS which added to it was `vuetable ui blue selectable unstackable celled table fixed`

There is a section where you can give width to each column, I have done that too. But semanticUI table is not letting that apply until I remove the option `fixed` from `vuetable ui blue selectable unstackable celled table fixed`..

[image]

now the username is being fully shown. but widths are not still being applied.

what is a proper way to show a full table with width 100% and get as wide as column width goes? and also show scroll on the bottom its already there.

You can check this Snippet for test https://codesandbox.io/s/rwlp0446r4

Comment: can you plz add a snippet. this will help us to understand your problem better. thanks

Comment: I have added one.

Comment: i have added width to the table and and gave `overflow:scroll` to the parent div. And you can give specific width to each th and td if you want. Hope this helps you. thanks . https://codesandbox.io/s/m5p36pk749